# I need to find the baseline for application metrics (eg CPU utilization,Response time).pls help

Tags: python

I have historical values for these metrics.Please suggest some approach to find this.The baseline has to be dynamically generated based on the selected duration.

Data ::

```
6/6/18 3:40 AM  26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
6/6/18 3:35 AM  26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
6/6/18 3:35 AM  26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
6/6/18 3:30 AM  26  TargetResponseTime  0.07
6/6/18 3:30 AM  26  TargetResponseTime  0.05
4/22/18 2:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.05
4/22/18 2:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.05
4/22/18 1:50 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.09
4/22/18 1:50 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.09
4/22/18 1:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 12:50 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.17
4/22/18 12:45 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.40
4/22/18 2:05 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 1:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 12:50 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.17
4/22/18 12:45 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.40
4/22/18 8:05 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 8:05 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 7:55 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 7:55 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 7:25 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.57
4/22/18 7:15 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 7:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 7:25 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.50
4/22/18 7:25 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.28
4/22/18 7:15 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 7:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 11:45 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.16
4/22/18 11:45 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.16
4/22/18 10:45 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/22/18 10:45 AM    26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/29/18 4:05 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
4/29/18 4:00 AM 26  TargetResponseTime  0.00
```